# предпринята попытка ссылки на удаленную функцию (при попытке передать ifstream в функцию)

Tags: c++, fstream

Объявление функции в начале кода:

```
string readtext(ifstream file, string text);
```

Сам код:

```
ifstream input;
string text;
input.open("W:/input.txt"); 
readtext(input, text);
```

После main сама функция:

```
string readtext(ifstream file, string text)
{
    string temp;
    for (int i = 0; file.eof(); i++)
    {
        file >> temp;
        text = text + temp;
    }
    return text;
}
```

Ошибка компилятора:

```
на функцию "std::basic_ifstream<_Elem, _Traits>::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream<_Elem, _Traits> &) [с _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]" (объявлено в строке 883 из "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\fstream") нельзя ссылаться, так как эта функция удалена
```

Comment: Попытка копирования объекта ifstream. Конструктор копирования данных объектов явно удален. Принимайте по ссылке

Answer (score 1):

Копировать потоки нельзя! а именно это вы и делаете, передавая поток по значению...

```
string readtext(ifstream& file, string text);
```

Вот так заработает.

Только на всякий случай — вы отдаете себе отчет, что после вызова

```
readtext(input, text);
```

в переменной `text` так ничего и не появится? я уж молчу о применении `eof()` в `for (int i = 0; file.eof(); i++)`...

Если вы уж так хотите просто выбросить все пробельные символы из файла и считать все в одну строку (это следует из вашего кода), то лучше уж делать так:

```
string readtext(ifstream& file);

int main()
{
    ifstream input;
    input.open("W:/input.txt");
    string text = readtext(input);

}

string readtext(ifstream& file)
{
    string text, temp;
    while(file >> temp) text += temp;
    return text;
}
```